# SharePoint How can I change the text in "Add new Item" button of a List?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I got a question..How can I change the text in "Add new Item" button of a List?

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize ribbon. Ribbon customization refrence http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff630938.aspx#odc_sp14_qn_WorkingwithSharePointRibbon_RemoveButton

In a nutshell y can remove "New Item" using following xml

```
<HideCustomAction Id="Ribbon.Documents.New.Controls.DemoHelloWorldButton" Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.Controls._children">
</HideCustomAction>
```

And add a new one.

Alternatively, you can use Reflector or any another decompiler to find Resourse file name and key used to render "Add new item" and chage it.

Comment: Thanks, but where can I type in the xml code? in Sharepoint designer?

Comment: the one that you provided was document library...how about a list? how can i edit the text?